# By what names are the walking dead known?

Tags: the-walking-dead

Each group of people seem to have labeled the walking dead by different names.

Here's a few I can recall off hand (I think):

```
Name        | Group
--------------------------
Walkers     | Rick's group
Biters      | Woodbury (The Governor)
Roamers     | Alexandrians
Growlers    | The Saviors
```

What is the complete list (so far)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is somewhere between a "Trivia" question and a "List" question, both of which are discouraged.

Comment: @JohnnyBones Well, I actually really want to know the answer. This is not intended to be a "puzzle" or similar challenge. I am asking for someone who has noted all the names to share them here. I also find it linguistically interesting to see what aspects of the walking dead the writers thought most characterizes them. Further, this question is answerable. Is there a way to rephrase this that won't incur your wrath?

Comment: There's no "wrath", but the site has rules.  These types of questions just typically aren't allowed.  Don't take it personally.  I mean, [if you **really** want to know...](http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/episode_scripts.php?tv-show=the-walking-dead)

Comment: @Johnny Bones I think the site rules allow list questions if it can have a definitive answer . Here's a couple examples http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/16540/man-of-steel-easter-eggs & http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/48786/what-were-all-the-references-in-deadpool/48795#48795 Edit : and it was discussed [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180335/are-there-good-list-questions-as-opposed-to-bad-list-questions)

Comment: Related: (SF&F SE) [What are all the different names survivors have called zombies?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/109291/7957)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Note:  This answer represents the best information I was able to find regarding the following media - *The Walking Dead* [comics](http://walkingdead.wikia.com/wiki/The_Walking_Dead_(Comic_Series)), [television show](http://walkingdead.wikia.com/wiki/The_Walking_Dead_(TV_Series)) (through the middle of season six), [print novels](http://walkingdead.wikia.com/wiki/Novel), and [Telltale story games](http://walkingdead.wikia.com/wiki/The_Walking_Dead_(Video_Game)), and the *[Fear the Walking Dead](http://walkingdead.wikia.com/wiki/Fear_The_Walking_Dead)* television show. Unless otherwise noted, mentions of television shows refer to *The Walking Dead*, not *Fear the Walking Dead*.**

**1. BITERS**

Various episodes and issues, as well as the print novels, most frequently used on by [Woodbury](http://walkingdead.wikia.com/wiki/Woodbury%2C_Georgia) residents and those they ally themselves with, such as [Cesar Martinez' camp](http://walkingdead.wikia.com/wiki/Martinez%27s_Camp).

**2. COLD BODIES**

Episode *[No Sanctuary](http://walkingdead.wikia.com/wiki/No_Sanctuary)*, used by [Terminites](http://walkingdead.wikia.com/wiki/Terminus).

**3. CREEPERS**

Episode S3E3, *[Walk with Me](http://walkingdead.wikia.com/wiki/Walk_With_Me)*, used by Merle.

**4. DEAD ONES**

Various episodes, used most often by Abraham, Eugene, and Rosita.

**5. FLOATERS/SWIMMERS**

"Floaters" and "swimmers" are the same thing, but the former is used in the comics, the latter in S2E4 *[Cherokee Rose](http://walkingdead.wikia.com/wiki/Cherokee_Rose)* by Dale, when the zombie in the well is discovered.

**6. GEEKS**

Used in both the comics and the show, more often in the early seasons than recently.  Glenn and Daryl used it more often than anyone else, although Shane and T-Dog also used it once or twice.  The first use on the show was from Glenn, in S1E2, *[Guts](http://walkingdead.wikia.com/wiki/Guts)*.  In the [Telltale story game (season two)](http://walkingdead.wikia.com/wiki/Season_2_(Video_Game)), Molly makes use of the term as well.

**7. LAMEBRAINS**

Episode S2E8, *[Nebraska](http://walkingdead.wikia.com/wiki/Nebraska)*, used by Dave and Tony, the two men Rick killed in the bar while trying to persuade Herschel to return home.

**8. LURKERS**

Much more common in the comics than on the show, where it is only used once, by the people of Woodbury, in S3E3, *Walk With Me*.  In the comics, almost all zombies are classified as either "roamers" (zombies who wander around seeking prey) or "lurkers" (zombies that sit/stand/lay in one place, apparently dead, until provoked or attracted to a nearby victim).

**9. ROAMERS**

Ubiquitous in the comics, limited to [Alexandrians](http://walkingdead.wikia.com/wiki/Alexandria_Safe-Zone_(TV_Series)) on the show.  See "lurkers" above.

**10. MONSTERS**

Various episodes, used by Andrea (S3E16, *[Welcome to the Tombs](http://walkingdead.wikia.com/wiki/Welcome_to_the_Tombs)*), and Jessie's son Sam (various episodes in seasons 5 and 6), among others.  Also employed by Brenda St. John, Chet, and Clementine in the Telltale story games.

**11. ROTTERS**

Various episodes of seasons 5 and 6, used by the people in [Grady Memorial Hospital](http://walkingdead.wikia.com/wiki/Grady_Memorial_Hospital) and by the [Wolves](http://walkingdead.wikia.com/wiki/The_Wolves).

**12. SKIN EATERS**

Used by Ana and Hippie Sam in S4E4, *[Indifference](http://walkingdead.wikia.com/wiki/Indifference)*.

**13. WALKERS**

The most frequently used name in every format of the franchise.  Primarily used by Rick's group and everyone they ally themselves with, but the strangers in S6E6, *[Always Accountable](http://walkingdead.wikia.com/wiki/Always_Accountable)* know what Daryl means when he asks "How many walkers have you killed?".  This might be because they have heard the term before, or they might have figured out what it meant through simple common sense and deduction.  It is also used by [Lee Everett](http://walkingdead.wikia.com/wiki/Lee_Everett_(Video_Game))'s group and their allies in the Telltale story games.

**14. STINKERS**

Used in the comics by a group of new arrivals in Alexandria, circa [issue #127](http://walkingdead.wikia.com/wiki/Issue_127) or so.

**15. SKIN BAGS**

Used by Lieutenant Moyers in the S1E5 *[Cobalt](http://walkingdead.wikia.com/wiki/Cobalt)* on *Fear the Walking Dead*.

**16.  MEAT PUPPETS**

Used in the comics by the [Saviors](http://walkingdead.wikia.com/wiki/The_Saviors_(Comic_Series)).

**17. EMPTIES**

Used in [issue 91](http://walkingdead.wikia.com/wiki/Issue_91) of the comics, by Jesus.

**18.  DEADIES**

Used in [issue 64](http://walkingdead.wikia.com/wiki/Issue_64) of the comics by the Hunters (who are the comic book analogues of the Terminites).  Sam says it in the episode *Indifference*.  Andrew St. John uses the term in the [Telltale story game (season one)](http://walkingdead.wikia.com/wiki/Season_1_(Video_Game)).

**19.  GHOULS**

Used in the comics by Tyreese, and in the Telltale story game by Carley (season one).

**20.  DEAD-HEADS**

Used on the show by Nicholas in S5E12, *[Remember](http://walkingdead.wikia.com/wiki/Remember)*.

**21.  INFECTED**

Used by Jenner at the [CDC](http://walkingdead.wikia.com/wiki/CDC) in S1E6 *[T.S. 19](http://walkingdead.wikia.com/wiki/TS-19)*, as well as by the military and civilians in the first season of *Fear the Walking Dead*.

**22.  GROWLERS**

Used by the Molly, one of the female Saviors at the Slaughterhouse in S6E13, *[The Same Boat](http://walkingdead.wikia.com/wiki/The_Same_Boat)*<sup>1</sup>

**23. ZOMBIES**

Yes, it is used in the comics, but only very rarely.  The images below come from [Volume 1:  *Days Gone Bye*](http://walkingdead.wikia.com/wiki/Volume_1%3A_Days_Gone_Bye) and [Volume 2:  *Miles Behind Us*](http://walkingdead.wikia.com/wiki/Volume_2:_Miles_Behind_Us), respectively.  There may be more instances of the word "zombie", but I haven't been able to find them.  It is also used in the Telltale story games.

[image]
[image]

**24.  REAL NAMES**

In several instances, people have referred to zombies whom they had known in life by their actual names:

- Greene family members and neighbors.  When Maggie tells Glenn to stop calling zombies "walkers", he asks her what she calls them.  She replies:

> "Mom, Shawn, Mr. and Mrs. Fisher, Lacey, Duncan."
>   -  *The Walking Dead*, S2E6, *[Secrets](http://walkingdead.wikia.com/wiki/Secrets)*

- Louise "Lou" Bush - Herschel's former neighbor (Herschel, S2E7, *[Pretty Much Dead Already](http://walkingdead.wikia.com/wiki/Pretty_Much_Dead_Already)*)
- Sophia - Carol's daughter (Carol, *Pretty Much Dead Already*)
- Amy - Andrea's sister (Andrea, S1E5, *[Wildfire](http://walkingdead.wikia.com/wiki/Wildfire)*; Shane, S2E6, *Secrets*)
- Wayne Dunlap - Zombie disemboweled to camouflage Rick and Glenn:

> RICK:  Wayne Dunlap, Georgia licence. Born 1979. He had $28 in his pocket when he died. And a picture of a pretty girl.  'With love, from Rachel.' He used to be like us – worrying about bills or the rent or the Super Bowl. If I ever find my family, I’m gonna tell them about Wayne."
>
> GLENN:  One more thing - he was an organ donor.
>   - *The Walking Dead*, S1E2, *Guts*

- Penny - The Governor's "daughter" (The Governor, S3E5, *[Say the Word](http://walkingdead.wikia.com/wiki/Say_the_Word)*)
- Susan - Madison and Trevor's neighbor (Madison, *Fear the Walking Dead*, S1E3, *[The Dog](http://walkingdead.wikia.com/wiki/The_Dog)*)
- Leon Basset - Rick's colleague at the Sheriff's Department.  Rick is with Morgan and Duane at the precinct when they spot a zombie in a deputy's uniform behind a chain link fence.  Rick says:

> Rick:  Leon Basset?  I didn’t think much of him – careless and dumb... but I can’t leave him like this.
>   -  *The Walking Dead*, S1E1, *[Days Gone Bye](http://walkingdead.wikia.com/wiki/Days_Gone_Bye_(TV_Series))*

Sources:

http://mentalfloss.com/article/62572/13-ways-saying-zombie-walking-dead
http://walkingdead.wikia.com/wiki/Zombies

---

<sup>1</sup>Credit to Bohemian for this one.

Comment: Great answer, but you left out at least "growlers" (used by the fat female saviour with lung cancer who lived at the power station or whatever it was)

Comment: @Bohemian - Yar, I should have mentioned that my list only goes up to the midseason break in season six.

Comment: Actually was that name that prompted this question. When I heard it I thought "what... *another* name for them. Just how many names *are* there?"

Comment: Orsm answer .... I was dreading the research I wanted to know this as well.

Answer (score 0):

I remember them being called lurkers in the comics meaning the ones that are "hiding" and quiet.
The whisperers also often call them the dead such as when alpha said "if the mom can't silence it [a baby] the dead will"